# Need to Retrieve Info from (NFT)Assets in Policy ID to see if they are in a Plutus Contract (smart contract) or Not using Blockfrost API

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, nft, blockfrost, python

I have a python script that retrieves the NFT asset name, and addresses of a specific policy ID using blockfrost API. Now I need to amend the script to add to the csv whether or not the specific asset is in a smart contract (plutus contract) or not. any ideas?

current script:

```
import requests,csv

blockfrost_api_key=input('blockfrost api key')
project_policy_id=input('project policy id')

base_api="https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0"

headers={'project_id':f'{blockfrost_api_key}'}

allAsset=[]

page=1

while True:
    response=requests.get(f'{base_api}/assets/policy/{project_policy_id}?page={page}',headers=headers)

    if len(response.json())==0:
        break

    for asset in response.json():
        temp={}
        asset_hex_name=asset["asset"][len(project_policy_id):]
        temp['name']=bytearray.decode(bytearray.fromhex(asset_hex_name))
        temp['asset']=asset['asset']

        allAsset.append(temp)
        
    page+=1

data=[]

for asset in allAsset:
    response=requests.get(f'{base_api}/assets/{asset["asset"]}/addresses',headers=headers)
    address=response.json()[0]['address']

    data.append([asset['name'],address])

    print(asset['name'])

file=open('snapshot.csv','w')
csvWriter=csv.writer(file,delimiter=',')
csvWriter.writerows(data)
file.close()
```

I'm a complete noob and followed a tutorial to get this far. Thanks for any help! greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are also there, all you need to do is to fetch the address using the `/addresses` endpoint and check if the address has a script flag.

Comment: @mmahut how do i do this exactly in my current script? I'm so new to scripting. thanks for any help

Comment: i figured it out with some help from a buddy. thanks